# Pass value 'AND'/'OR' dynamically using SolrPhpClient UI to Solr

Tags: php, search, solr, jetty

I am using SolrPhpClient UI for Solr. Here, I'm configuring user search input to appropriate input like 'prod_path:(mens athletic puma sneaker shoes)&q.op=AND' which works fine in case of Solr application but this input is not working fine when I'm using SolrPhpClient UI. I mean, it is giving same result for AND and OR. I want to pass value 'AND'/'OR' dynamically in case of SolrPhpClient UI. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I passed option(AND/OR) like this `$results = $solr->search($searchterm, 0, $limit,$option);` where Search is a function of Apache_Solr_Service class. In search function, I assigned the option value to params array like `$params['q.op'] = $option;`. I got result depending on AND/OR option.